# Hadoop: count frequency and then set variable in second map/reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In a single Hadoop program I have three Map/Reduce jobs. The first one should count the total number of words in my data set. The second and third Map/Reduce do something else depending on the number from the first Map/Reduce. Is there a way to set the output of the first Map/Reduce to a global variable to be used throughout the rest of the program?

My first thought was to have the first Reduce step write the number as an output and then have the second Mapper read this file, but I would rather not do this.

Comment: `but I would rather not do this.` why not?

Comment: It seems unnecessary. Why write a single integer out to a file, read it back into the same program and then delete that file when you could just keep it in your program the entire time?

Comment: Why not? It does not cost time/space. Its just a single write & read.

Comment: True, but it would be nice to write more sophisticated code building on this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the these 3 jobs in the one job? And you can define a global variable to keey the number.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. How to I assign the global variable the output of a reducer?

Comment: Try to set a  global variable in your mapred program to keep the result. When you first job completed(reduce), restore the result to the  global variable, and use the variable as input to the second mapred program(map).

Comment: Again, that is what I am trying to do but I don't know how to do that. The output of the reducer is written to a file or series of files. Is there a way to redirect that output to a variable? If yes, how do I do that (besides just opening up that file and reading the first line)? :)

Comment: Look the follow answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as follow, write the three map/reduce method in a same class file.
[image]

Comment: And then how are you assigning the output of the reducer to that variable?